# Coroutine loop freezes on unity3d run time

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, coroutine

this is my unityScript code that have a simple coroutine loop. this Code works very well with editor test but on mobile phone and real time test the counter freezes if you want to go to main menu and come back again for counting down.
in other words you start from level 1=>2(every thing is run very well) after that 2=>1 and when you again go to 2 level count down will freeze at first number!!

```
function Start () { 
    StartCoroutine("DoSomething");
}
```

-

```
function DoSomething () {
    for (var i = 5; i >= 0; --i) {  
        print("Future : \n" + i);
        yield WaitForSeconds(1);
        print("counting : \n " + i);
    }
}
```

why should this code work at first time and freeze at second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return finally the control from your yield, try this:

```
function DoSomething () {
    for (var i = 5; i >= 0; --i) {  
        print("Future : \n" + i);
        yield WaitForSeconds(1);
        print("counting : \n " + i);
    }
    yield return null;
}
```